# ActionScript contained in externally loaded SWF files will be ignored on iOS devices

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I am developing an IOS app in Flash CS6. I'm trying to load an external swf. The preloader loads the external swf. The loading itself seems to work. After loading the external swf, I add its movieclips to the stage. But strangely, on iOS devices, the movieclips are not added to stage.

Here's the code for the preloader:

```
package {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.display.BitmapData;
    import flash.display.Loader;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.system.LoaderContext;
    import flash.system.ApplicationDomain;


    public class Test extends MovieClip {
        private var lobbyBgAssetsLoader:Loader = new Loader() ;
        private var ldrContext:LoaderContext;

        public function Test() {

            var urlStr:String = "cards.swf";
            lobbyBgAssetsLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, LobbyBgAssetsswfLoaded);
            lobbyBgAssetsLoader.load(new URLRequest(urlStr));
            ldrContext = new LoaderContext(false,ApplicationDomain.currentDomain,null);


        }

        private function LobbyBgAssetsswfLoaded(e:Event):void
        {
            txt.text = "loaded complete  test ";
            var logoSmall:Bitmap = new Bitmap();
            var classDefinition:Class = lobbyBgAssetsLoader.contentLoaderInfo.applicationDomain.getDefinition("cardBg") as Class;
            txt.text = "after load ";
            var img:MovieClip = new classDefinition() as MovieClip;
            this.addChild(img);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I've edited your question so the code shows properly and so your problem is easier to understand.

Comment: here i want to acces movieclip from cards.swf ..from builder it is showing. but ipa instaled in ios device it is not showing..        Note:if we access that movieclip from main swf it showing..but the problem occur whenever we access that movieclip from external swf file..

Comment: I think you should add an event listener for `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` to check if it loads the external swf properly on the iOS device.

Comment: its loading swf file..for that i kept trace i.e :loaded complete test " it is showing in ios device..after that loading moviclip "card_bg" not showing and after taht line trace i.e "after load " not showing in ios device..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All actionscript gets converted into native Obj-C code when you compile your app for iOS. So even if your app is able to load an SWF file from the internet, the actionscript inside will not be converted to Obj-C.

Apple does not allow the actual flash player inside an iOS app, so an app cannot play back SWF content.

Comment: Thank you..is it possible to develop ios apps in flash ?@Kokodoko

Comment: Yes you can use AIR. I assumed that's what you were doing?

Comment: K.but my project contains some external swf files .now how can i load that external swf files ..is there any way to load external swfs...@Kokodoko

Comment: You can load external SWFs but not external code. This can be solved by including the external code at compile time and only using external SWFs for assets (graphics, timeline animations). Here's an explanation: http://blogs.adobe.com/airodynamics/2013/03/08/external-hosting-of-secondary-swfs-for-air-apps-on-ios/